# Does the never type in TypeScript have specific behaviour when used as a type parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Lets' have two types

```js
type Type1<T> = T extends never ? { type: "A" } : { type: "B", value: T }
type Type2 = never extends never ? { type: "A" } : { type: "B", value: never }
```

I would expect that `Type1<never> = Type2` but TypeScript thinks otherwise.

When I define two constants with the seemingly same types and assign them the same values

```js
const var1: Type1<never> = {
    type: "A",
}

const var2: Type2 = {
    type: "A",
}
```

then the second constant is accepted by TypeScript but the first one is reported as an error: TypeScript states that the type of var1 is never and cannot be assigned a value.

TypeScript version is 4.9.5

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think** when a generic is given before `extends` typescript distributes it and since never is an empty union Type1 resolves to never. But in Type2 never is not distributed so it extends never.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31751

Comment: Interesting. So apparently the fix is to write `[T] extends [never]`, right?

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the link. The sad part is that I know about this distributive behaviour of TypeScript but I just could not think of never as a union type :(

Comment: @MoritzRingler Yeah